# Is there a way to analyze static maps usage beyond the basic console reports?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

Does anyone know if it's possible to dive deeper into our static maps API usage data than we get through the console? We're being charged and I'm trying to make sure that I understand where all the requests are coming from!

First stop was to prevent bots from trying to index static map content but the requests remained high.  At 50k pageviews for the whole site per day from visitors I'm just a little suspicious that we'd be hitting 112k static map views per day...

I'm hoping there are ways/strategies to figure out which pages are causing the most views and which user agent strings/IPs.

Comment: Was thinking about a middleman script on my own server to intercept API requests and pass thru so I can monitor usage on my side but was worried about the terms of use. I'm not caching but would be serving the images from our script vs letting google do it directly.

Comment: The usage reports listed in the [API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/) are strictly for billing purposes. It sounds like you're after traffic reports which is something you'd get from Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

Add a serverside script as [icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#CustomIcons) to the StaticMap-URL.

The url of this script(icon) should contain a random parameter to prevent google from caching this script(icon), and additionally
parameters that are populated with the desired details(url of the current page, IP, UserAgent)

The response of the script should be an image that is suitable to be used as a icon for a static map(may be a 1x1 transparent png)

The script may store the supplied parameters in a DB, you should be able to create detailed statistics of the StaticMaps-loads.

Comment: As I mentioned in my own comment - I was considering a server side script to act as a middleman to serve the images but my concern is that it would be outside the terms of service for caching these objects or putting something between the google server and the user's browser.